# Flow state - Rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq

Im trying to monitor the state of my queues in rabbitmq and trying to develop a small script to monitor their states. I am able to detect the running and idle states from the HTTP API rabbitmq provides. I want to push my queue into a flow state now to see the HTTP response I get and make a check for that. How do I do that? I tried pushing large volumes of data through my queue but rabbitmq is still able to handle it well. I am pasting my scripts below:

send.py

```
import pika

message = ' '.join(str(i) for i in range(1000000))
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='test3')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='test3', body=message)

print "[x] sent Hello World"

connection.close()
```

receive.py

```
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='test3')

print '[*] Waiting for messages...'

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print "[x] received %r" % (body,)

channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='test3', no_ack=True)


channel.start_consuming()
```

Comment: i'm not super sure how a flow state is triggered, but what happens if your consumer sleeps? which should backup your queue very quickly if i you keep sending messages

Comment: I do I put my consumer to sleep?